# How to prevent the Kill() process by another?

Tags: c#

In C# it's possible to block the  **Kill()** process by another(user or program) ??

I want to close my application only by the "Close Button" and block other way.

Comment: Nope (unless your process is a rootkit).

Comment: You can't do it. Any process can call the terminate of your process.

Comment: So when you program hangs, I have no way to shut it down. Thank you very much, but no.

Comment: That would be bad design, if your application crashes it could never be closed (Hello Memory leak). Sounds like you're developing a questionable application if you want to prevent kill processes from being run against it.

Answer (score 2):

I've used C# for years and I've never come across such a mechanism. You would need some way to tell the OS that the current process is somehow protected from being killed. It's maybe more of an OS question than a language question, actually.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11186026)

Comment: "It can't be done" is not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to create a Windows Service instead of a simple Process. This way, I think you could tell in the Windows services tab to always have it active and execute it as much as you would like. For instance:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 12000; //Execute the process every 12 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            Runner.WriteErrorLog("Timer ticked and some job has ben called!");
            Runner.Start();
            Runner.WriteErrorLog("Job done!!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Runner.WriteErrorLog("ERROR!!! " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This WOULD NOT prevent the termination of your process but it would enable you to read the log and find if it has been terminated and re-launch it.